# I'm new to Coinbase and was wondering how to buy and sell on it, and what the buying and selling means for me? Please and thank you

Tags: coinbase

I'm new to Coinbase and my balance is zero, what does buying and selling mean for me, and how should I do it?

Comment: Hi there. I'd suggest reading their support pages: https://support.coinbase.com/. There's a section on buying and selling. What it means for you will depend on where you live, and what regulations Coinbase has to adhere to in your country. I'm going to suggest your question be flagged as off-topic as it's more about a third-party service than Ethereum itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coinbase lets you buy and sell Ethereum using USD. You can hook up your bank account and then purchase the amount of Ether that you'd like using your bank account.

After you make your purchase and receive the Ether, you can tap Sell to sell off your Ether at the market price back to USD.